# Can I send a message directly to the poison message queue for testing purposes?

Tags: powershell, msmq

I want to test a poison message handling service, and would like to be able to send messages directly to the poison message sub queue.  I've used the following powershell script:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queue = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myserver\private$\testqueue;poison"
$queue.Send("dummy1");
```

Which results in the following error:

> Exception calling "Send" with "2" argument(s): "The specified format
>   name does not support the requested operation. For  example, a direct
>   queue format name cannot be deleted."

Is there a simple way to send directly to a subqueue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can send directly to subqueue. All that you can is move message between "main" queue and one of its subqueues. So only way is to send to main queue, and then move it to subqueue.

I didn't use powershell for this but this seems to be the command:

```
Parameter Set: Transactional
Move-MsmqMessage -DestinationQueue <MessageQueue> -InputObject <MessageQueue> -Message <Message> [-Transactional] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Shameless plug: you can use our product [QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/) for playing around with MSMQ messages, including moving to/from subqueue.